# Page moves on Refesh/Reload?

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla2.5

Simply Put, This website I am working on at - http://learning.realsense.co.uk/ shifts focus on reload.

To Test, go to home page, go to the bottom of the page , hit refresh and Viola you'll be thrown top.

Tested this in IE, FF

I've got some valuable feedback that it works fine on Chrome. Thanks guys!

Any comments as to why this will happen in the other two? ( They kind of form the priority :) )

Comment: If it could help you, i've tested it in Chrome and it work fine.

Comment: I just tested it in FF and it doesn't put me back at the top. But it does move me a bit further up. The last thing I can seen on my screen is the light gray area with the "request a trial" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the 'slideshow' area is generated by Javascript after the page has loaded, hence pushing the page down.

Solution: Set a height to the slideshow container using CSS.